# CSI on Windows Nomad nodes

Tags: hashicorp, nomad

Is there a way to configure the CSI plugin on Nomad Windows nodes? With SMB or NFS volumes. Does anyone have a working solution?

Thanks!

mcr.microsoft.com/k8s/csi/smb-csi - looks like it not support Nomad (Kubernetes only).
docker.io/democraticcsi/democratic-csi - can't configure on Windows nodes.

I found working solutions for Linux only.